# Working with 2 arrays in PHP with keys and values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in php and I need to make a new array out of them the arrays are...

```
array(2) { 
    ["required"]=> array(4) { 
          ["broom handle"]=> int(1) 
          ["metal plate"]=> int(1) 
          ["bolt"]=> int(2) 
          ["motivation"]=> int(1) 
    } ["userItems"]=> array(4) { 
          ["broom handle"]=> string(4) "1000" 
          ["metal plate"]=> string(4) "1000" 
          ["bolt"]=> string(4) "1400" 
          ["motivation"]=> string(4) "1000" 
    }
}
```

What I want to do is take the value of `userItems` and divide it by the value of `required` where the key matches, I have tried using `array_walk` and `array_map` but can never get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array['userItems'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value / $array['required'][$key];
}
```

You take it from here.

If the order is identical, you can even do it nicely with an `array_map`:

```
$newArray = array_map(function ($req, $userItem) { return $userItem / $req; },
                      $array['required'],
                      $array['userItems']);
```

Comment: Ye the order will always be identical as I am making the original array manually thanks @deceze